# Is it possible to access speech-to-text audio clips for debugging?

Tags: applications, samsung, keyboard, voice-recognition, microphone

Is there a way to access the audio clip that gets used for Google's speech-to-text transcribing?

I've been getting increasingly inaccurate output using Google's speech-to-text output. After discovering my Samsung phone has more than one microphone, I'm  wondering if perhaps this could have to do with either which microphone is getting used, and/or if there's any audio processing being applied which is affecting accuracy.

If I could debug these waveform/recordings myself, I could at least see whether the input itself is the source of the inaccuracy, or whether it's something else.

Comment: Issues relating to programming is off-topic here. You can just run any number of audio recording apps to see what is being recorded to check if there is a device problem.

Comment: https://myactivity.google.com/myactivity?restrict=vaa

Answer (score 0):

https://myactivity.google.com/myactivity?restrict=vaa suggested by  [alecxs](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/170470/alecxs)
will let you access audio recordings from Google assistant but Gboard  voice typing:

[image]

Tested with  Android 12 with a Google Pixel 6.